# Check the SQL sentence generated by excute python 3.5 mysql.connecter

Tags: python, mysql

I often excute sql sentence with mysql.connector

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='pass', host='localhost', database='db1')
cur = conn.cursor(buffered=True)


sql = "select * from mysql where symbol =  %s and life = %s"
data = (data1,data2)
cur.execute(sql,data)
```

Normally, this is not problem , but sometimes error happens with some small misstakes.

If I could check sql generated directly, it is the great help for debuging.

```
select * from mysql where symbol = 'test' and life = 'mylife'
```

I have tried thanks to @hunzter advice.

```
try:
    cur.execute(sql,data)
except:
    pprint(cur._last_executed)
    sys.exit()
```

However it shows

```
AttributeError: 'MySQLCursorBuffered' object has no attribute '_last_executed'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is `cursor._last_executed`. You can print it out, even if exception occurs.

Comment: Thank you ! Howeber I have tried with try /except, `AttributeError: 'MySQLCursorBuffered' object has no attribute '_last_executed'` occured

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? I'm using just fine.